# Autocomplete search issue with Chrome in Bootstrap 3

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have working search field which  brings data from database, it has autocomplete as well. It is working fine in firefox but there is an issue in chrome.

When i start typing in firefox example: John Anthony Doe, i can write Doe and it will bring up John Anthony Doe or any data with Doe in it but in Chrome it is only bringing data if i start with with first letters i.e John.

Any idea how can I fix it? Is there a setting in chrome which i have to do?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple form and ran it in both, chrome and firefox.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="testText" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And the result was same as you mentioned.

So basically, *displaying the auto-complete is browser based and there is no such setting to change the way it searches from the previous inputs. Firefox searches wildcards like `%text%` while chrome like `text%`. That's a built in feature.*

---

**For IE :**

The Internet Explorer AutoComplete feature can be enabled and disabled by following the steps below.

1. Open Microsoft Internet Explorer.
2. Click Tools and then Internet Options.
3. In the Internet Options window click the Content tab.
4. Click the AutoComplete button.
5. Check form.

*But again, IE also behaves like chrome for your case*

> To solve this manually, you can create your own auto-complete :

By fetching data from db using AJAX as the user types the text, search the text however you want in db (`%text%` or `text%`).

Then populate the `datalist` for that text box with the fetched values.

Comment: In IE9 and IE10, autocomplete doesnt work at all. It does not show data with you start typing, is that a  browser issues as well?